# Length hiding (by adding a random number of bytes to the responses) for preventing BREACH attack in spring MVC

Tags: spring, azure, httpresponse, azure-application-gateway, breach-attack

Length hiding (by adding a random number of bytes to the responses) is one of the mitigations for a BREACH attack. How can we implement this in a spring application?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a random number of bytes to the responses that your application sends out by using a Spring MVC interceptor.In the `postHandle` method, you can use the `HttpServletResponse` object to add a random number of bytes to the response body and set the `Content-Length` header to the correct value, taking into account the additional bytes that you have added.
You can take a look at [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

Comment: I tried to set the headers for responses using java Filter.  Added random value for content-security-policy header and it worked. But when I tried to set random values for Content-length header ,it didn't worked

Comment: Could you share your code

Comment: This is what I tried for setting  content length  Eg.httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Length", "1010101");

Comment: used the same setHeader() for Content-Security-Policy and it worked

Comment: please try the following
response.setContentLength(response.getContentLength() + numBytes);

Comment: Thanks. There is no getContentLength() for HttpServletReponse

Comment: yeah, my bad just set the updated number. Did this resolve your issue?

Comment: No. The issue still exists